# How can I use the $ character as a value in a string on powersell?

Tags: scripting, powershell

How can I define a variable with a string that contains the character "$"

Something like

```
$Variable = "$String"
```

Doesn't work

Comment: The first one doesn't work. Using single quotes works. Thank you!!

Comment: Have added as an answer. It it helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: The first one works in some situations. 
In something like this use 
(Get-Content $Path) | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace 'old string', 'new string'} | Set-Content $Path
use '' instead "" doesnt work but \ works:
Defining variables \ doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Single quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 6):

Escape `$` with  `. So, that should be:

```
$Variable = "`$String"
```

*That's the key above TAB key in most keyboards.*

Alternatively, as Mitch mentioned, single quotes will work as well:

```
$Variable = '$String'
```